# Can't capture special (non-printable) characters in any editable component

Tags: delphi, barcode, barcode-scanner, delphi-2007

I have a problem with Delphi components and barcode-scanner emulating a keyboard. When I scan 2d code it enters "pure" string but without any special characters like GS (group separator, ASCII 0x29). When I do the same in for example Notepad++, special character is visible and can be easily copied to aforementioned Delphi control. Is there any way to capture whole string with special characters directly? I tried MaskEdit, RichEdit, ...

Comment: Well, you are using a non-Unicode  version of Delphi, so you may be experiencing character conversions that are losing data during the "keyboard" input. On the other hand, why are you capturing barcodes using an Edit control at all? Doesn't the scanner provide an API for delivering scanned codes directly to your app? Otherwise, you might consider using the Win32 Raw Input API, or a keyboard hook, to capture keystrokes directly.

Comment: FWIW, ASCII `0x29` is a printable character, a right parenthesis: `')'`. Did you mean `29` or `0x1D`, which is indeed a group separator (GS)?

Comment: What is the actual brand/model of the scanner you are using? What does its documentation say exactly about capturing the scanner's output?

Comment: Thanks for the answers and hints. I managed to catch the characters on KeyPressEvent.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Most barcode scanners simply emulate keyboard to insert barcode value to your application. Why? Becouse this way you get compatibility with just about any application that is able to accept keyboard input. Having a special API would limit compatibility only to applications that are designed to have support for such API

Comment: @Ewka Since most barcode scanners emulate keyboard input don't forget that they could be affected by input language settings of your computer.